# Lock orientation view

Tags: orientation

My app opens in portrait. When your turn to lanscape, a second landscape view appears. I want the user to be able to lock the screen in this position so turning the device to potrait does not change the view back to the first view unless they unlock it.

Comment: What phone system are you talking about?

Comment: iOS programming with latest version of Xcode